# Check if the estimator is unbiased

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

For $X_i\sim U[0,a]$ where $i=1,2,\dots,n$ so, $E(X_i)=\dfrac a2$.

Is $a'=\max\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ an unbiased estimator of $a$?

This is what I thought.

Since $a'=\max\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}=X_k$ such that $X_k\ge X_h$ for any $h$,

$E(a')=E(X_k)=\dfrac a2$.

Therefore $a'$ is not an unbiased estimator.

However, I don't think it is properly solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\text{cdf}$ of the maximum of $n$ iid random variables is the $n^{th}$ power of the single $\text{cdf}$. In this case,
$$\text{cdf}(X)=\left(\frac xa\right)^n.$$

The expectation is

$$\int_0^a x\frac na\left(\frac xa\right)^{n-1}dx=\frac{na^{n+1}}{(n+1)a^n},$$ which is smaller than $a$ (but asymptotically unbiaised for large $n$).

---

Your reasoning is wrong in that the distribution of $\max\{X_k\}$ is not the same as that of a single $X_k$ (obviously the $\max$ favors the larger values), and the expectations do not match.

Comment: Isn't pdf of the X then becomes (n/a)(x/a)^(n-1)??

Comment: The link between cdf and bias is not clear to me. Is there a reference available?

Comment: @JanRothkegel: the link is between the expectation and the bias.

Comment: @Newt: right, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $B_a(a')$ is the bias of the estimator $a'$ for $a$. That is,
$$B_a(a')=\mathbb E \left [a'-a \right]$$
Always, $a' < a$, because $P(X=a)=0$. Therefore $B_a(a')<0$ and (more important) $B_a(a') \ne 0$. It follows that $a'$ is biased.

By the way: $a'$ is the MLE of $a$. Asymptotically (or approximately for large samples) it is unbiased.

Comment: But why does a′<a hold?

Comment: Because $max\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}<a$ or as described in my post: $P(X=a)=0$. You never hit the parameter.